# Array index for an ordered pair

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, indexing

Hi I need create a ordered pair using this logic (no functions):

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A = [2,5,7];
B = [6,2];
LA = len(A)
LB = len(B)
Maux = [];
print(type(Maux))

for i in range(0,LA,1):
    for j in range(0,LB,1):
        
        Maux[i-1*LB + j , j] = [A[i] , B[j]] 

print(Maux);

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I compile the system says: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

I read about this problem and I think is an incorrect index to access the matrix.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare `Maux` to be a `dict` your code will work: initialize it with `Maux = {}`.

Also, get rid of the semicolons at line-ends: you're writing Python, not C++ Java Pascal etc.

You don't need "`,1`" at the end of `range(...)` calls, commas should be followed by single spaces for readability, you don't really need `LA` but it's ok, and you don't need to multiply anything by `1`. With these improvements:

```
A = [2, 5, 7]
B = [6, 2]
LA = len(A)
LB = len(B)
Maux = {}
print(type(Maux))

for i in range(0, LA):
    for j in range(0, LB):
    
        Maux[i - LB + j, j] = [A[i] , B[j]] 

print(Maux)
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>
{(-2, 0): [2, 6], (-1, 1): [2, 2], (-1, 0): [5, 6], (0, 1): [5, 2], (0, 0): [7, 6], (1, 1): [7, 2]}
```